# Display a component within an i18n text in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, vuetify.js, vue-i18n

I want to add a button component in a paragraph text. I can do it manually like the 1st sample below. But, due to my text comes from i18n values, I need to import it in the text. Is there any way to put the button like a variable within the i18n text like the 2nd sample?

```
<p>
  1) Use
  <v-btn @click="attachmentDialog.show(item)" v-on="on">
    <v-icon small left>mdi-pencil</v-icon>Edit
  </v-btn>
  button to add booking.
</p>
<p>
  2)
  {{ $t("no_booking_info", { buttonName: $t("edit") }) }}
</p>
```

en.js

```
export default {
  no_booking_info: "Use {buttonName} button to add booking."
}
```

[image: code result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something about component interpolation [here](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/interpolation.html#basic-usage) on vue-i18n documentation.

And this is how I figured my case out:

```
<i18n path="no_booking_info" tag="p" for="edit">
  <v-btn class="mx-2" @click="editAction">
    <v-icon left>mdi-pencil</v-icon>
      {{ $t("edit") }}
  </v-btn>
</i18n>
```

en.js

```
export default {
  no_booking_info: "Use {0} button to add booking.",
  edit: "Edit"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understand well your question.

```
Use <v-btn v-html="$t('no_booking_info', { buttonName: $t('edit') })" /> button to add booking.
```

Comment: Unfortunately the "Use ... button to add booking." text must be translated for different languages. So it must be called from i18n resources as $t("no_booking_info").

Comment: Ah. Will the string "Use ... button to add booking" change by user?
How about this? Have string set for i18n like this "Use {{edit button}} button to add booking", and replace using regEx to "Use <button .. /> button to add booking". then, display using `v-html`.

Comment: The button must be rendered before to be replaceable and it doesn't be rendered until runtime.

Comment: I solved the problem and shared as answer above.